# Table Format Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

```
event
time:00.00
event no.:01
Type:A
result:success

event
time:00.01
event no.:02
result:success 

event
time:00.02
event no.:03
Type:B
result:fail
```

I have the above file and I want to write this file in table format like this:
time|event no.|Type|result|

```
00.00|01|A|success|
00.01|02||success|
00.02|03|B|fail|
```

How to do this using linux shell scripting?

Comment: ok, so which part of your script isn't clear? where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F' *: *' 'NF>1{a[$1]=$2; next}
  /^event/ && NR>5{print a["time"], a["event no."], a["Type"], a["result"] OFS;delete a;next}
    END{print a["time"], a["event no."], a["Type"], a["result"] OFS}' OFS='|' file

00.00|01|A|success|
00.01|02||success|
00.02|03|B|fail|
```